# Different result roc_auc_score and plot_roc_curve

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest, roc, auc

I am training a `RandomForestClassifier` (sklearn) to predict credit card fraud. When I then test the model and check the rocauc score i get different values when I use `roc_auc_score` and `plot_roc_curve`. roc_auc_score gives me around 0.89 and the plot_curve calculates AUC to 0.96 why is that?

The labels are all 0 and 1 as well as the predictions are 0 or 1. 
CodE:

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier(random_state =42)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train[target].values)
pred_test = clf.predict(X_test)
print(roc_auc_score(y_test, pred_test))
clf_disp = plot_roc_curve(clf, X_test, y_test)
plt.show()
```

Output of the code (the roc_auc_Score is just above the graph).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are feeding the prediction classes instead of prediction probabilities to
`roc_auc_score`.

From [Documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html):

> **y_score:** array-like of shape (n_samples,) or (n_samples, n_classes)

> Target scores. In the binary and multilabel cases, these can be either probability estimates or non-thresholded decision values (as returned by decision_function on some classifiers).

change your code to:

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier(random_state =42)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train[target].values)
y_score = clf.predict_prob(X_test)
print(roc_auc_score(y_test, y_score[:, 1]))
```

Comment: Probabilities of higher class has to be used. So should be `roc_auc_score(y_test, y_score[:,1]`.

Comment: yes, you are right. Thanks, updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The ROC Curve and the roc_auc_score take the prediction probabilities as input, but as I can see from your code you are providing the prediction labels. You need to fix that.